# xslt sorting not working

Tags: xslt

basically i want to sort data by level and i'm getting an error. I'm a newbie to xslt. i tried the below code but not working.

here is my xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="XSLTEx1WT.xsl"?>
<Modules>
    <module code="CSE2041">
        <name>Web Technologies II</name>
        <credit>3</credit>
        <level>2</level>
    </module>
    <module code="CSE2031Y">
        <name>Object Oriented Software Development</name>
        <credit>6</credit>
        <level>2</level>
    </module>
    <module code="CSE1041">
        <name>Web Technologies I</name>
        <credit>3</credit>
        <level>1</level>
    </module>
</Modules>
```

here is my xsl file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:variable name="deptCredit" select="99"/>
    <xsl:variable name="myBorder" select="1"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>XSLT Exercise 1</title></head>
            <body>
                <table border="{$myBorder}">
                    <thead><tr><th>Module Name</th><th>No. of Credits</th><th>Level</th></tr></thead>
                    <tbody>

                        <xsl:apply-templates>
                            **<xsl:sort select="level" data-type="number"/>**
                        </xsl:apply-templates>
                    <tr><td colspan="3">Departmental credits needed: <xsl:value-of select="$deptCredit"/></td></tr>
                    <tr><td colspan="3">Percentage cleared: <strong> <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(//credit/text()) div $deptCredit,'##.##%')"/></strong>
                    </td></tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="module">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@code"/>
            <tr><xsl:apply-templates select="*"/></tr>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="name">
        <xsl:call-template name="sjName"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@code">
        <tr style="background-color:silver;">
            <td colspan="3" style="text-align:center;">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="credit">
        <td style="color:blue;"><strong><xsl:value-of select="text()"/></strong></td>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="level">
        <td style="color:blue;"><strong><xsl:value-of select="text()"/></strong></td>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="sjName">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="contains(../@code,'Y')">
                    <td style="color:orange;font-weight:bold;"><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <td style="color:lime;font-weight:bold;"><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>               
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

i have tried the above but its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to change this:

```
<xsl:apply-templates>
    <xsl:sort select="level" data-type="number"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

to this:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="Modules/module">
    <xsl:sort select="level" data-type="number"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

Comment: Yours answer is better, I've deleted mine. +1